# working on variables generated from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Yesterday I discovered something that I don't realy understand. I am using a pandas.DataFrame to store medical data. Here's my problem: I wanted to do some operations on some data in this dataframe (df). Therefor I copied the data out from the dataframe into a variable(df_part) then I did the operations and then I wanted to store it back into the dataframe. What happend was that the operations were already done in the dataframe even if I only worked on the variable. Appears to me as if the variable represents a pointer not a copy of the content as I expected. Would appreciate if someone can help me to understand this issue. Thanks in advance. (I'm working with python 3.6)
Some example code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1],columns=("t1","t2"))
df
Out[2]: 
    t1   t2
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN

df.iloc[0,1] = np.ones((2,2))
df.iloc[1,1] = np.zeros((2,2))
df
Out[5]: 
    t1                        t2
0  NaN  [[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
1  NaN  [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]

df_part = df.t2[0]
df_part
Out[7]: 
array([[1., 1.],
       [1., 1.]])

df_part[:,:] = 0
df_part
Out[9]: 
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])

df
Out[10]: 
    t1                        t2
0  NaN  [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]
1  NaN  [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Use `df_part = df.t2[0].copy()`. Without this, you are just pointing to an existing object via a *view* rather than acting on a *copy*.

Comment: This is somewhat well documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy), although maybe with an emphasis more on the opposite case: users try to do an assignment on the original dataframe, but end up using a copy

Comment: I did some operation on each element in df_part. But as you can see this operation ( ... = 0) was also done on the dataframe df. Why is that so? I thought the df_part is a copy of data in df and therefor independent. I am quite new to python. Was using Matlab before.

Comment: @avigil I found this. But it wasn't that clear for me.

Comment: You are using an `object` dtype data-frame. You then select an object out of it, mutate it, so of course that object will still be mutated inside your data-frame.

Comment: Ok. I got it, thank you guys. But it is not that obvious for me. As I am used to Matlab I thought of getting a copy of a chosen part from the whole dataframe object and not a variable pointing on the chosen part in the dataframe object. Need to get used to that.